# difference in between CNN and Inception v3

Tags: machine-learning, cnn, inception

What is the difference in between the inception v3 and Convolutional neural network?

Comment: The Inception architecture is a convolutional model. It just puts the convolutions together in a more complicated (perhaps, sophisticated) manner, which allows the model to be a little more robust to the variance in size of the objects within images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Inception models are types on Convolutional Neural Networks designed by google mainly for image classification. Each new *version* (v1, v2, v3, etc.) marks improvements they make upon the previous architecture.

The main difference between the Inception models and regular CNNs are the **inception blocks**. These involve convolving the same input tensor with **multiple filters** and **concatenating** their results. Such a block is depicted in the image below.

[image]

On the contrast, regular CNNs performs **a single** convolution operation on each tensor.

Inception-v3 is Deep Neural Network architecture that uses inception blocks like the one I described above. It's architecture is illustrated in the figure below.

[image]

The parts where the layers "branch off" and then are merged together again are the inception blocks described previously.

You can read more about Inception-v3 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.00567).

Comment: The various filter sizes help the model to generalise for objects of different sizes, in that it offers a range of focus levels. Also worth noting is that the 1x1 convolutions are included in the 3x3 and 5x5 *branches* as a means to reduce the computational cost. they shrink the sizes of the tensors by reducing the third dimension in a 3d tensor.